# react router Link wrap div background doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Just got a wired issue with react-router `<Link>`, when I wrap a div with a background in it, it does not show the image, but if I comment out the Link, the background can show up, does anyone encountered the same issue?

```
       <Link to={{
                    pathname: "/productDetail",
                    search: "?productId=" + props.product.productid
                }}>
                <div
                    className="image"
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(correctURL)`
                    }}
                />
       </Link>
```

The url is correct I can guarantee cause when I comment out the Link it works fine.

Update:
not working one:

```
  <Link to={{
                    pathname: "/productDetail",
                    search: "?productId=" + props.product.productid
                }}>
                <div
                    className="image"
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(correctURL)`
                    }}
                />
   </Link>

sass file:
   .image { 
      width:100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

Here is my solution:

```
  <Link className="link" to={{
                    pathname: "/productDetail",
                    search: "?productId=" + props.product.productid
                }}>
                <div
                    className="image"
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(correctURL)`
                    }}
                />
  </Link>

sass file:
link {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    .image { 
      width:inherit;
      height: inherit;
      background-color: white;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to define and put some height.

```
       <div 
        style={{
        backgroundImage:`url('https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lMD31ltzL.jpg')`,
        height:'500px'}}>
        </div>
```

Or

```
let myUrl = 'https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41lMD31ltzL.jpg';
```

define like this

```
        <div 
        style={{backgroundImage:`url(${myUrl})`,
        height:'500px'}}>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I finally figure it out, it's because of my SASS file, when I add a link, the SASS structure changed so the width and height I set for the div is not working.